# Basis in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am taking an introductory linear algebra course, and I am stuck on this problem:

Explain why the set $W= \{(a,b,c)\ |\  a+b+c=0\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. After, find a basis for the subspace $W$.

I don't really know how to start it, so if you guys could answer my question, I would greatly appreciate it.

thanks

Comment: always start with definitions

Comment: Should that $=c$ be a $+c$?

Comment: Hi there, yes. I apologize that I made a mistake. It took me a while to see that :(

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace) for additional information to help here.

Comment: Suppose you have $(a,b,c),(d,e,f) \in W$ and $k \in \mathbb R$. Then you want to check that $(a,b,c)+(d,e,f) \in W$ and $k(a,b,c) \in W$. To do that, you want to show that those two vectors have components summing to $0$, so that they satisfy the condition on $W$.

Answer (score 2):

Prove the basic conditions a *subset* must fulfill to be a subspace: (a) check that the zero vector is in $\;W\;$ , (b) show that if two vectors are in $\;W\;$ so is their sum, and (c) if a vector $\;w\in W\; $ and $\;r\;$ is any scalar, then also $\;rw\in W\;$ .

As for a basis: observe that $\;a+b=0=c\;$ leaves us with only one free choice, for example $\;b\;$ . Once $\;b\;$ is chosen we already have no more choices as it must be $\;a=-b\;,\;\;c=0\;$ . This tells us that the dimension is $\;1\; $ (Remember: the ammount of free choices), so now only take your favourite number, which is $\;1\;$  (it can't be zero as then you get the zero vector, which can't be part of any basis. Why?), and $\;\{(1,-1,0)\}\;$ is a basis of $\;W\;$ .

Comment: Also, at the time of posting, it did indeed read "$a+b=c=0$" but the op has since edited to be $a+b+c=0$.  If you have the time, shouldn't take long to fix it to reflect the current version of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The subspace is the null space of the matrix 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
and hence is a $2$ dimensional subspace by the rank nullity theorem. One can check that $(1,-1,0)^T$ and $(0,1,-1)^T$ are two linearly independent vectors in the null space so that they form a basis for $W$.

Answer (score 0):

By what you write we have that $c=0$ which means we've already lost 1 dimension, then we have $a+b=0$ which means it's a line only, a line is definitionally a subspace of the 3 dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

Just go by the definition of subspace: a subspace is a subset of the space that is also a vector space. You can easily prove that any linear combination of vectors $(a, b, c)$ for which $a+b + c = 0$, also satisfies this condition. Therefore, it is indeed a subspace.

I can elaborate on this if the rest of the proof is not clear to you.